# Redirect images folder using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect my images folder (specifically jpg files) to a different location when a mobile/tablet is used. This is what I've currently got, but it keeps bringing up a 500 Internal Server Error when I view the images.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry [NC]
RewriteRule ^images/(.+)\.(jpg)$ http://www.domain.co.uk/images/mobile/$1.$2 [QSA,L]
```

Thanks

Comment: Of course we don't read tea leaves here. Show us Apache's error log messages mentioning your issue. Usually error messages are self-explanatory as well.

Comment: Is mod_rewrite module activated? `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: yes, everything else is rewriting fine

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because of looping. Try the below code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/images/ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(png|gif|jpe?g)$ images%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

This will rewrite image URLs only when /images/ is not present in URI.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `/mobile/`then ? Except `/images/`

Comment: I need the images folder to change to images/mobile, so I've changed it to:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.co.uk$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/images/mobile/ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg)$ images%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]

But nothing is happening?